# A question about convergence of integrals with respect to levy measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose $g(x):\mathbb R^p\to \mathbb R$ is a bounded continuous function such that:
\begin{equation}\label{8.3}
    \quad g(x)=1+o(|x|),\quad  \hbox{ as }  |x| \rightarrow 0 \quad \hbox{  and } \quad g(x)=O(1 /|x|),\quad  \hbox{ as }  |x| \rightarrow \infty.
\end{equation}
i.e.:
\begin{equation}\label{8.4}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g(x)-1}{|x|} =0 \quad \hbox{  and } \quad |g(x)| \leq M \frac{1}{|x|},\, \forall\, x \geq x_0.
\end{equation}

Let $(\mu_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\mu$ be p-dimensional **Levy measures** such that:

\begin{equation}\label{L}\tag{L}
\mu_n(E) \longrightarrow \mu(E),\quad \hbox{ as }n \to \infty\quad\left( \forall E \in \mathcal C_\mu, \hbox{class of continuity sets, and }\,0 \notin \bar E.\right)
\end{equation}

Remember that $\mu$ is a Levy measure if $\int_{|x|\leq \epsilon} |x|^2 d \mu < 0$ and $\int_{|x|> \epsilon} d\mu< \infty$, for all $\epsilon >0$ ( There are other equivalent definitions).

**Question**

Suppose
\begin{equation}\label{H}\tag{H}
\int_{\mathbb R^p} |x|^2d\mu_n \leq C< \infty, \quad \forall\, n
\end{equation}
(Given (\ref{L}), it is strightforward to show that (\ref{H}) implies $\int_{\mathbb R^p} |x|^2d\mu \leq C$).

So, assuming (\ref{L}) and (\ref{H}), how to show that the following convergence:
\begin{equation}\label{abc}\tag{I}
\int_{\mathbb R^p} x[1-g(x)] d\mu_n \longrightarrow \int_{\mathbb R^p} x[1-g(x)] d\mu < \infty, \quad (n \to \infty)
\end{equation}

**Remark**

If (\ref{H}) is not true, we have a counterexample. Suppose $p=1$, $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|^2}$. Take $d\mu_n(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}\mathbf{1}_{(0,n)}dx$ and $d\mu(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}\mathbf{1}_{(0,\infty)}dx$. Note that for any $\epsilon>0$:
$$\int_{|x|>\epsilon}d\mu_n = \int_{\epsilon}^n\frac{1}{x^2}dx=\frac{1}{\epsilon}- \frac{1}{n} \longrightarrow \frac{1}{\epsilon} = \int_{|x|>\epsilon} d\mu(x), \quad(n \to \infty)$$
I think that this is sufficient to prove (\ref{L}).
Now, note that $x[1-g(x)]= \frac{x^3}{1+x^2}$. Thus, as $n \to \infty$:
$$\int_{\mathbb R} x[1-g(x)] d\mu_n =  \int_{0}^n \frac{x}{1+x^2} dx= \frac{1}{2}\ln(1+n^2)\longrightarrow \infty = \int_{\mathbb R} x[1-g(x)] d\mu$$

Help!

(The criteria for choosing to give the bounty will be for whoever answers the correct answer the fastest.)

Comment: Don't you need continuity of $g$? What happens if $\mu_n=\delta_{x_n}$ and $\mu=\delta_x$?

Comment: Thanks. In fact, $g$ is continuous and bounded. If $\mu_n = \delta_{x_n}$ and $\mu = \delta_{x}$, then if $x_n \to x$, we have $$\int_{\mathbb R^p}x[1-g(x)] d\mu_n = x_n[1-g(x_n)]\to \int_{\mathbb R^p} x[1-g(x)] d\mu = x[1-g(x)]\quad(n \to \infty)$$ and $\int_{\mathbb R^p}  |x|^2 d \mu_n =| x_n|^2 \to \int_{\mathbb R^p} |x|^2 d\mu= |x|^2$, as $n \to \infty$. Where do you want to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to obtain

\begin{equation}
\label{WC}\tag{WC}
\int_{\mathbb R^p} x[1-g(x)] d\mu_n \longrightarrow \int_{\mathbb R^p} x[1-g(x)] d\mu , \quad (n \to \infty)
\end{equation}

from the narrow convergence of $\mu_n$ to $\mu$, you need that $|x|$ to be uniformly integrable w.r.t. $(\mu_n)_{n\geq 1}$. This can be obtained from

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb R^p} |x|^2d\mu_n \leq C< \infty, \quad \forall\, n.
\end{equation}

Indeed, let $f_M$ be a bounded continuous function statisfying $0\leq f\leq 1$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ s.t. $|x|\leq M$ and $f(x)=1$ for all $x$ s.t. $|x|\geq 2M$. Hence,

$$
\int_{\mathbb R^p} |x|^2d\mu_n\geq \int_{\mathbb R^p} f_M(x) |x|^2d\mu_n \geq M \int_{\mathbb R^p} f_M(x) |x|d\mu_n.
$$
Thus
$$
\sup_{n\geq 1}\int_{\mathbb R^p} f_M(x)  |x|d\mu_n \leq \frac{1}{M}\int_{\mathbb R^p} |x|^2d\mu_n\leq \frac{C}{M}.
$$

Take $\varepsilon >0$ and $M$ large enough so that the

\begin{equation}
\label{abs}\tag{I}
C/M<\varepsilon\qquad\text{    and }\qquad\int_{\mathbb R^p} f_M(x)  |x|d\mu <\varepsilon.
\end{equation}

We then have
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^p} x[1-g(x)] d\mu_n=\int_{\mathbb R^p}f_M(x) x[1-g(x)] d\mu_n+\int_{\mathbb R^p} (1-f_M(x))x[1-g(x)] d\mu_n.
$$
It follows from the definition of $f_M$ that $x\to (1-f_M(x)) x[1-g(x)]$ is bounded continuous so
\begin{equation}\label{C}\tag{C}
\int_{\mathbb R^p} (1-f_M(x))x[1-g(x)] d\mu_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\int_{\mathbb R^p} (1-f_M(x))x[1-g(x)] d\mu
\end{equation}

Finally,by \eqref{abs},
$$
\begin{multline*}
\left|\int_{\mathbb R^p} x[1-g(x)] d(\mu_n-\mu)\right|\leq\left|\int_{\mathbb R^p} f_M(x)x[1-g(x)] d(\mu_n-\mu)\right|+\left|\int_{\mathbb R^p} (1-f_M(x))x[1-g(x)] d(\mu_n-\mu)\right|\\
\leq 2\varepsilon\|1-g\|_{\infty}+\left|\int_{\mathbb R^p} (1-f_M(x))x[1-g(x)] d(\mu_n-\mu)\right|
\end{multline*}
$$
but
$$
\left|\int_{\mathbb R^p} (1-f_M(x))x[1-g(x)] d(\mu_n-\mu)\right|
$$
goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. This gives the result.

**Addendum**: If the narrow converge is not assumed but rather that
$$
\mu_n(E)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\mu(E)
$$
for all measurable $E$ such that $\mu(\partial E)=0$ and $0\notin E$, I think one can proceed as follows:

First, note that this condition implies the narrow convergence of the sequence $\mu_n\left(B(0,\delta)^c\cap \cdot \right)$ to $\mu\left(B(0,\delta)^c\cap \cdot \right)$ for all $\delta\in \mathbb{R}_{+}\setminus D$ where $D$ is some denumberable subset of $\mathbb{R}_{+}$. So the previous argument gives \eqref{WC} for integrals over $B(0,\delta)^c$.

Now, Hypotheses on $g$ implies that, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta\in \mathbb{R}_{+}\setminus D$ s.t., for all $x$ with $|x|<\delta$
$$
|1-g(x)|\leq \varepsilon |x|
$$
Hence,
$$
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{\mathbb R^p} x[1-g(x)] d(\mu_n-\mu)\right|&\leq\left|\int_{B(0,\delta)} x[1-g(x)] d(\mu_n-\mu)\right|+\left|\int_{B(0,\delta)^c} x[1-g(x)] d(\mu_n-\mu)\right|\\
&\leq \varepsilon\int_{B(0,\delta)} |x|^2 d(\mu_n+\mu)+\left|\int_{B(0,\delta)^c} x[1-g(x)] d(\mu_n-\mu)\right|\\
&\leq 2\varepsilon C+\left|\int_{B(0,\delta)^c} x[1-g(x)] d(\mu_n-\mu)\right|
\end{align*}
$$
which allows to conclude. Just a last remark:

- For the narrow convergence on $B(0,\delta)^c$, one needs remark that the set $$I_{n,k}=\{\delta>1/k \mid \mu(\partial B(0,\delta))>1/n \}$$
  must be finite, because otherwise would contradict that $\mu$ is finite away from $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you provide details for:
$$\int_{\mathbb R^p} f_M(x) |x|^2d\mu_n \geq M \int_{\mathbb R^p} f_M(x) |x|d\mu_n\,\,?$$
Note that for $x$ such that $M\leq |x|$, we have $Mf_M(x) |x|\leq f_M(x) |x|^2$ trivially. For $|x|\leq 1/M$, it is also trivial. However, I have the impression that $f_M(x) |x|^2 < Mf_M(x) |x|$, for $1/M \leq |x| \leq M $. At least, that's what the graph I plotted for the case $f(x)=|Mx|-1$ with $1/M\leq |x|\leq 2/M$ shows me.

Comment: You are right. I have messed up my defintion of $f$. This should be good now. Sorry ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your provision. Note that equation (L) (in my question) is not quite a weak convergence, as we have the constraint that $0 \notin \bar E$. This makes the convergence of the integrals not valid for any continuous and bounded function. For convergence of the integrals to be true, the function also has to vanish in a neighborhood of zero (look at this https://cutt.ly/swkmC6tJ). Thus, the convergence you claim in (C) is not immediately valid for $(1-f_M(x)) x[1-g(x)]$, as it does not vanish close to zero. I'm also finding it strange not to use the properties of the $g$ function.

Comment: My answer only covered the narrow convergence + bounded second moments. I have put some insight to treat the case of hypothesis $(L)$. Hope this helps. I really don't think that the second hypothesis on $g$ is useful under hypothesis (H).

Comment: Note: I replaced weak convergence by narrow convergence as the context is not  probability measures, these are differents.

Comment: Dear, thank you. I'm confused. In order for the narrow convergence of the restricted measures on $B(0, \delta)^c$ to be valid, it is necessary that $x[1-g(x)]$ is bounded and continues in $\overline{B(0 , \delta)^c}$ and this does not seem to be the case. $x[1-g(x)]$ is unbonded.  How then do you argue that $\left|\int_{B(0,\delta)^c} x[1-g(x)] d(\mu_n-\mu)\right|$ converges to $0$ ?

Comment: Indeed, the idea is It can be derived from the first part of my answer (before addendum) by just follows what I wrote but with $B(0,\delta)^c$ in place of $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Comment: I was wondering if convergence over $B(0, \delta)^c$ is perhaps simpler than I thought. It might be possible to show $h(x)=|x[1-g(x)]|\leq|x|^2$-this is true for $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|^2}$. Fixing $k\in\mathbb N$, note: 
$$\int_{\delta<|x|\leq k}|h(x)|d\mu_n\leq\int_{\delta<|x|\leq k}|x|^2d\mu_n\leq \int_{\mathbb R^p}|x|^2d\mu_n\leq C$$
where $h$ now is bounded and cont on $[\delta<|x|\leq k]$. So, we can take the limit to conclude that $\int_{\delta<|x|\leq k}h(x)d\mu<C$ for all $k$. I just don't know if it would be enough to do $k\to\infty$ to complete the result.

Comment: This is not true in general. But you can have $h(x)\leq \frac{1}{\delta}\|1-g\|_\infty |x|^2$ for $x$ such that $|x|>\delta$.

Comment: Dear, thank you for your contributions. I already accepted your answer. Just to finish, can we say that it is also possible to conclude using a uniform integrability argument?

Comment: Yes: the strategy would be 1) get rid of the problem at $0$ using the addendum so you just have to show your result for $\int_{B(0,\delta)^c} x[1-g(x)] d\mu_n$ 2) Use argument of uniform integrality (like the one before the addendum) to show that the former integral converge to the desired limit.